# I am taken to a white screen, when trying to access website via XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I have installed XAMPP so that I can locally develop a WordPress website.

The installation was successfully installed, with no errors appearing in the XAMPP Control Panel.  I have successfully uploaded the WordPress files as after uploading such files, I was taken to the WordPress Dashboard.

That said, whenever I try to view the website, I am taken to a Blank screen.

Any ideas on why this may be?  I have had a looked at a few answers here but none seem to rectify my issue.

**A few suggestions already tried:**

- Remove tick next to the 'Use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming
  connections' message within the Skype settings
- Remove the Dashboard
  folder from the XAMPP files.
- Go to http://localhost:8080/ rather
  than http://localhost/wordpress/

Any further suggestions, for me to try, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your local php error log, and also try deleting your htaccess file. Also swap to default template/rename plugins folder to rule out a WP problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the installation instructions, via the software's website, was slightly out of date.  Such instructions, seems to now have been updated.  I can now load my web files, and display them locally, with no problems.