# My phpmyadmin in Xampp localhost doesn't load anything. How Can i do?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I have recently installed Xampp on my Windows 11 PC. yesterday, I couldn't open the phpMyAdmin page! It shows the white screen and nothing appeared... home localhost opens and no problem in it. the screenshot is below:
[phpMyAdmin error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYK73.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218619/i-am-taken-to-a-white-screen-when-trying-to-access-website-via-xampp